# Nef line bundles over complex analytic spaces

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, line-bundles

Let $L$ be a line bundle over a compact complex manifold $X$ with a Hermitian metric $\omega$: $L$ is said *numerically effective* (*nef*, for short) if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth Hermitian metric $h_{\epsilon}$ on $L$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\Omega_{h_{\epsilon}}\geq-\epsilon\omega;
\end{equation*}
that is the curvature form $\Omega_{h_{\epsilon}}$ of the Chern connection on $L$ (with respect to $h_{\epsilon}$) can have an arbitrary negative part.

In order to define the *nef line bundles* over **complex analytic spaces**:

> are there references about Hermitian metrics, differential forms, Chern connections in the **complex analytic space** framework?

Any answer, comment, advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in Demailly's "Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry"?

Comment: Yes, I have. But Demailly does not treat of vector bundles over complex analytic spaces.

Comment: You won't find anything about Hermitian metrics (do those even make sense for complex analytic spaces?) or chern connections but I think you can find differential forms in Grauert/Remmert - Coherent analytic sheaves and in Fischer -  Complex analytic geometry. Other than that, can't you use some equivalent definition from algebraic geometry to define it for complex analytic spaces?

Comment: @Horstenson After a couple of days and research on Internet: I started as you suggest; I am consulting Fischer, Grauert - Remmert but *Theory of Stein Spaces*, and Gunning - Rossi *Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables*. However, thank you for your advices.

Comment: Ok, good luck. From what I've seen so far complex analytic spaces are not heavily presented in the literature, especially in english. There's more in french and german.

Answer (score 2):

The standard reference about differential forms on complex analytic spaces is V. Ancona and B. Gaveau, **Differential Forms on Singular Varieties: de Rham and Hodge Theory Simplified,** Chapman and Hall, 2006. It doesn't seem to treat Chern classes, but there is some discussion of Hermitian metrics (appearing on resolutions, I think).